# Clientside validation of a textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, textbox, client-side-validation

I have an asp.net control textbox, clicking on which a jquery timepicker appears and user can select any time.But I want to validate the selected time so that it is one hour greater than the current time in the client side. I mean when textbox value will be changed it should be validated. Can anyone help me how to do this?

Comment: which `jquery timepicker` is this?

Answer (score 0):

The input that the client's selection goes into will have an id. Do

```
$('#that_id').change(function() {
Validation Code/////
})
```